# A login form without a challenge (adapter)

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to implement form-based authentication in a native iOS app, but I need to login without receiving a challenge, I want to open a form and login. I implemented a ChallengeHandler class which contains `isCustomResponse` function.  In this function, I checked in the response if it contains (j_security_check) so I can tell if there's a challenge in the response.

I have two problems:

1. Why I'm not getting the challenge from the server? I tried to call many protected adapters but I never received a response contains j_security_check.
2. When I try to log in without a challenge, just by calling submitLoginForm, I get an error from the server, why I'm getting this and how can I solve it?

> Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:241'
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Invalid gadget request
>   format: /iOSNativeAPI/iOSnative/0/j_security_checknull. Unknown
>   handler path: j_security_check

**Edit:**

The environment I'm working on is swift 1.2 with xCode 6.4 for the native app, the Worklight staging server I'm integrating with is 6.1, after deploying the native API on the server I tried to login using a realm that is called "LDAPRealm", I created a challenge handler for this realm if type MyChallengeHandler after I extended the ChallengeHandler class:

```
var ldapAuthChallengeHandler1 = MyChallengeHandler(realm: "LDAPRealm")
```

I want to login without responding to a challenge, so I called the submitLoginForm function from the created challenge handler:

```
ldapAuthChallengeHandler1.submitLoginForm("j_security_check", requestParameters: ["j_username": "xxxxx@gmail.com", "j_password": "11111111"], requestHeaders: nil, requestTimeoutInMilliSeconds: 0, requestMethod: "POST")
```

However, I received the error and I can't figure out why.

Comment: 1) This is a programming Q&A website. You are expected to provide code that can be debugged. 2) did you check your implementation compared to the provided sample for form-based authentication? https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/form-based-authentication/form-based-authentication-native-ios-applications/

Comment: @IdanAdar how can I enable the app authenticity for native ios api? here is a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pbp2setj165spl/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-07%20at%202.08.50%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: What does this have to do with this question? There is an authenticity tutorial, follow it. Focus on this question.

Comment: Can you provide step-by-step reproduction of this error with j_securitu_check, and a full description of your development environment?

Comment: @IdanAdar I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Form-based authentication does not support pre-emptive authentication. Meaning you can only login from a response from a challenge.

Regarding why your challenge is not being called, it's difficult to tell with the provided information.

Check Wireshark, put logs everywhere, see if you receive a challenge at all.
Also maybe provide your authenticationConfig.